# curve shows the design on the nexus 6

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I do design for android. I have a few phones. they have different resolutions. I have a design in resolving 1440X2560 px. screen has 3 squares with different widths. width of 1440 pixels in xxxhdpi = 360 dpi.I have the width for each layout. Now if I run the application on Samsung Galaxy Note 4 (1440x2560 640 dpi) everything looks as it should. Now if I run the application on Nexus 6 (1440x2560 ? dpi) the picture is not the entire screen. I found that the nexus 6 has resolution betwen xxhdpi and xxxhdpi. the question is how I mark the screen so that it looked the same on all phones? or I should not use  dpi?[enter link description here](https://pp.vk.me/c625126/v625126208/2204e/4N4Z1jGNjFY.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#ffff2622">
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#ff42ff20">
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#ff4934ff">
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.cz/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html) the Nexus 6 really is between `xxhdpi` and `xxxhdpi` with scale around 3.5. I am not a fan of layout weighting as @Squonk suggested so I would reccomend using [dimensions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension).

Create values folders for different screen widths such as `values-w320dp`, `values-w360dp`, `values-w410dp` etc. There you can define your dimensions for different screen widths.

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="left_column">60dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="middle_column">200dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="right_column">100dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

In your xml you can then reference `layout_width="@dimen/left_column"`

I would also recommend setting only the left and right column widths and have the middle one fill the remaining space. You could do that with a `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you want to create your 'squares' to have a ratio of 60:200:100 (which is also 3:10:5). Try the following to set width by `layout_weight`...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="#ffff2622">
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:background="#ff42ff20">
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:background="#ff4934ff">
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Using `android:layout_width=0dp` and `android:layout_weight=` will give each element a size based on a percentage of the sum of all weight values.

Comment: but then on the other screens crooked